# contour integral and branch cut question

Tags: complex-analysis, definite-integrals, contour-integration, complex-integration, branch-cuts

Any ideas on how to approach this kind of question?? What does the question means I for each of the branches?? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

With the branch cut along the positive real axis, we have

$$z^{1/5}=R^{1/5}e^{i\phi/5}e^{i2n\pi/5}$$

for $n=0,1,2,3,4$.  The index $n$ defines the branches.

Hence, we have

$$I_n=-R^{6/5}e^{i2n\pi/5}\int_0^{2\pi} e^{i6\phi/5}\,d\phi$$

Can you finish now?

Comment: hi @Mark Viola , thanks for helping...can I say that even though the diagram drew the circle in the sense it passes through the branch cut but actually it doesn't right??

Comment: Also I don't have to solve the contour like the one shown in the link??? https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/8d/Keyhole_contour.svg/180px-Keyhole_contour.svg.png

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.

Comment: The contour begins at $\pi =2\pi ^-$ and ends at $\phi =0^+$.

Comment: I'm not sure as to your meaning of "solve the contour like the one shown in the link."